# Работа сайта на SQLAlchemy остановилась из-за одной случайной ошибки. Правильно ли я работаю с сессиями?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Есть сайт на Flask, SQLAlchemy, PostgreSQL. При создании новой записи случилась ошибка, что PK ключ этой таблицы уже занят. Обычная таблица, с id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY. id генерятся всегда только автоматически.

И вот после этой ошибки каждое обращение к базе данных, даже просто на чтение, падало с такой ошибкой:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely) (psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_table_pkey"

До этого в этом сайте я использовал Flask-SQLAlchemy, таких проблем никогда не было. Но после перехода просто на ванильный SQLAlchemy, ошибка эта случилась.

Работа с бд ведется через `db_session`, который определен в `__init__.py` модуля:

```
_engine = create_engine(c.DATABASE_URL)
_Session = sessionmaker(bind=_engine)
db_session = _Session()
```

Создание записей делаю через `db_session.add(new_ojb); db_session.commit()`

Видите вы в такой работе с SQLAlchemy что-то неправильное? Почему при создании записи в таблице появился дубль PK, почему потом последующие запросы из-за этой ошибки перестали обрабатываться?

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка происходит из-за того, что предыдущая транзакция не была откачена. Для того чтобы ее откатить достаточно сделать `session.rollback()`.

Обычно комитят изменения в алхимии следующим образом:

```
try:
    session.commit()
except DatabaseError, e:
    session.rollback()
    logger.error('...')
```

**Обновление**

`session.flush()` записывает изменения в базу, но не коммитит их, они считаются не персистентными (но видны, например, уже при запросах в базу внутри этой транзакции), то есть если после этого будет сделан `session.rollback()` они пропадут.
Вот есть еще [пост](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4202016/1909485) по этому поводу с комментарием от создателя алхимии.

**Обновление 2**

Ловить исключения **надо** в любом случае, иначе алхимия будет тебе выкидывать такую ошибку, и это абсолютно правильно c её стороны. Ты можешь эти ситуации обрабатывать явно через try/except, через менеджер контекста либо декоратор, выбирай что по вкусу. :)
По поводу ошибки генерации ID, теоретически они могут возникнуть при таком [кейсе](http://doc.artofweb.ru/doc/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B2_PostgreSQL), смотри секцию *подводные камни*. Это всё что я могу сказать, глядя на приведённые данные.

Для подстраховки от возникновения такой ошибки снова ты можешь сделать 2 вещи, нигде не выполнять INSERT с заранее переданным PK и поставить на этой таблице `setval` на самый большой текущий PK. [Подробнее](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-sequence.html).

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю: если я не использую try/except блоки для работы с БД, то мне надо использовать не session.commit(), а что-то типа session.flush()?

Comment: @p2mbot, Обновил ответ.

Comment: Да, уже прочел, что просто session.flush() не поможет, без .commit() ничего не сохраняется.

Но тогда остается вопрос: в чем проблема, что я делаю не так. Этот сайт работал под такой же нагрузкой раньше, но с использованием Flask-SQLAlchemy. 
Ипсользовать блоки try/except __ВЕЗДЕ__ не вариант.

Получается что из-за кода:
```_engine = create_engine(c.DATABASE_URL)
_Session = sessionmaker(bind=_engine)
db_session = _Session()```

получилось две большие проблемы:
1) id перестал автоматом генериться правильно
2) из-за любой проблемы с БД все дальнейшие запросы не работают

Comment: Никогда не делаю INSERT с переданным PK, всегда во всех проектах генерятся исключетельно на уровне БД/ORM. И всегда в качестве id использую SERIAL без предварительных настроект.

И проблема появилась лишь исключетельно когда начал сам использовать SQLAlchemy без каких-либо дополнительныз помощников типа Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Пока понял что session у SQLAlchemy надо закрывать. + для многопоточных приложений надо использовать scoped_session.

http://piotr.banaszkiewicz.org/blog/2014/02/22/how-to-bite-flask-sqlalchemy-and-pytest-all-at-once/

Но проблема c PK еще все равно осталась.